# cakephp insert data in two table within one model and control

Tags: cakephp

I have Two Table ones and twos I have A Foreign Key in 'two' table  two_one_id
I Want to insert data in both table at a time , means insert data within one form, so how to manage controller and model, can I make  one model and one controller for this ? then How To Create The Model And Controller For This
Which Type Of Relation Should Have I Prefer For Both Table?

I Have Made Two Different Tabele One.php and Two.php
and I Have Made Two Controller OnesController.php and twosController.php
Can I Use Scaffold In Both Of Them And Using Scaffold  Can I Insert Data In Two Table Within A Controller And Model, If It Is Possible Using Scaffolding , Then How Done It, Or In This Code I Have Tried Without Scaffolding , Manual Manage View    */

/*One.php File

```
            public $displayField = 'name';

            public $hasOne = array(
                'Two' => array(
                    'className' => 'Two',
                    'foreignKey' => 'two_one_id',
                    'conditions' => '',
                    'fields' => '',
                    'order' => ''
                )
            );
        }
```

//Two.php

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

    class Two extends AppModel {

               public $displayField = 'sname';


            public $belongsTo = array(
                'One' => array(
                    'className' => 'One',
                    'foreignKey' => 'two_one_id',
                    'conditions' => '',
                    'fields' => '',
                    'order' => ''
                )
            );
   }
```

//OnesController.php

```
        <?php
        App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
        /**
         * Ones Controller
         *
         * @property One $One
         * @property PaginatorComponent $Paginator
         */
        class OnesController extends AppController {

        /**
         * Helpers
         *
         * @var array
         */
            public $helpers = array('Html','Form');

                public $uses = array('One','Two');


            public $components = array('Paginator');


            public function index() {
                $this->One->recursive = 0;
                $this->set('ones', $this->Paginator->paginate());
            }


            public function view($id = null) {
                if (!$this->One->exists($id)) {
                    throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid one'));
                }
                $options = array('conditions' => array('One.' . $this->One->primaryKey => $id));
                $this->set('one', $this->One->find('first', $options));
            }

                    public function add() {
                if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                    $this->One->create();
                    if ($this->One->save($this->request->data)) {
                        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The one has been saved.'));
                        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                    } else {
                        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The one could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                    }
                }
            }


            public function edit($id = null) {
                if (!$this->One->exists($id)) {
                    throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid one'));
                }
                if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
                    if ($this->One->save($this->request->data)) {
                        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The one has been saved.'));
                        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                    } else {
                        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The one could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                    }
                } else {
                    $options = array('conditions' => array('One.' . $this->One->primaryKey => $id));
                    $this->request->data = $this->One->find('first', $options);
                }
            }

                    public function delete($id = null) {
                $this->One->id = $id;
                if (!$this->One->exists()) {
                    throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid one'));
                }
                $this->request->onlyAllow('post', 'delete');
                if ($this->One->delete()) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The one has been deleted.'));
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The one could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
                }
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }}
```

Comment: If you are trying to create 2 new models from the same form (ie. a new `One` and a new `Two`), and at the same time associate them, I think you'll have to do it like this: Save the `One` object first, get the ID via `$this->One->getLastInsertId();`, save the `Two` object using the `id` we just found to create the association.

Comment: Everything of your question is covered here http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    You Just Set Following Code to Your Controller
    OnesControllers.php
    public function add() {
            if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                $this->One->create();

            }
                 if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
            // We can save the User data:
            // it should be in $this->request->data['User']

            $one = $this->One->save($this->request->data);

            // If the user was saved, Now we add this information to the data
            // and save the Profile.

            if (!empty($one)) {
                // The ID of the newly created user has been set
                // as $this->User->id.
                $this->request->data['Two']['two_one_id'] = $this->One->id;

                // Because our User hasOne Profile, we can access
                // the Profile model through the User model:
                $this->One->Two->save($this->request->data);
            }




        } 
And Set This in Your View
view/one/add.ctp

<div class="ones form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('One'); ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Add One'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('name',array('rows' => '10'));
        echo $this->Form->create('Two');
        echo $this->Form->input('sname');
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into: `$this->One->saveAll($this->request->data)`

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array